# Why can't I sent emails from vtiger?

Tags: vtiger-crm

I have configured an outgoing and incoming mail box settings in [vtiger](https://www.vtiger.com/) 5.04.

I created a new marketing campain, added a contanct (lead) to it and try to send e-mail to that contact.

When I click "send" I get:

> Please check the current user mailid. It should be a valid mailid to send Emails".

But I configured everything!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your outgoing mail server is well configured (CRM Settings->outgoing server)
If well configured, you should get a mail in your inbox:

```
Dear admin,

This is a test mail sent to confirm if a mail is actually being sent through the smtp server that you have configured.
Feel free to delete this mail.

Thanks and Regards,
Team vTiger
```

If not working, please provide log information.